# Have eclipse copy .class files to additional target folder?

Tags: eclipse

I have an eclipse project. By default, my .class files are being put here:

```
/projectname/build/classes
```

is there a way I can have eclipse also copy those files to an *additional* folder destination, every time the project is built?

I could write a script to do this myself, but was hoping there was some kind of hook in eclipse to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Eclipse will place compiled classes in only folder. Set the final folder you want to keep the classes in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't have the native ability to output to multiple locations, but you can probably accomplish it yourself by [adding a custom builder to your project(s)](http://bewarethepenguin.blogspot.com/2008/08/customizing-builds-for-your-eclipse.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could write an Ant script for this and add it as a builder to your project. See the [Eclipse documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-92_project_builders.htm) for an example.